# Spring Boot Soap :How to initiate @WebService into Spring Boot Application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, soap

I am migrating a web service into spring boot.
From wsdl i am able to generate following interface

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://tsb.hcl.com/terp/ws/v2", name = "Terp-v2")
@XmlSeeAlso({com.hcl.psi.tsb.schema.common.ObjectFactory.class, com.hcl.psi.tsb.schema.offering.ObjectFactory.class, com.hcl.psi.kil.system.message.ObjectFactory.class, com.hcl.tsb.terp.ws.schema.ObjectFactory.class, com.hcl.psi.tsb.schema.task.ObjectFactory.class, com.hcl.psi.tsb.schema.servicecontract.ObjectFactory.class, com.hcl.psi.tsb.schema.project.ObjectFactory.class, com.hcl.tsb.tsb.ObjectFactory.class, com.hcl.psi.tsb.schema.customer.ObjectFactory.class})
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
public interface TerpV2 {

    @WebMethod(operationName = "GetServiceContracts")
    @WebResult(name = "GetServiceContractsResponseType", targetNamespace = "http://tsb.hcl.com/terp/ws/schema", partName = "payload")
    public com.hcl.tsb.terp.ws.schema.GetServiceContractsResponseType getServiceContracts(
        @WebParam(partName = "payload", name = "GetServiceContractsType", targetNamespace = "http://tsb.hcl.com/terp/ws/schema")
        com.hcl.tsb.terp.ws.schema.GetServiceContractsType payload
    ) throws TerpServiceFault;
```

I am not sure how to initiate it in Spring Boot application form baeldung website. I tried implementing following code:

```
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/ws/*");
    }


    @Bean(name = "TerpService")
    public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema countriesSchema) {
        DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("Terp-v2");
        wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/tsb/tone/ws/v2/TerpService/");
        wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("http://www.baeldung.com/springsoap/gen");
        wsdl11Definition.setSchema(countriesSchema);
        return wsdl11Definition;
    }

    @Bean
    public XsdSchema countriesSchema() {
        return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("countries.xsd"));
    }
}
```

But I am not sure how to initiate above interface or it's implementation into spring boot context?

Do i need to write whole contract classes manually?

Can anyone guide me about same. Thanks

Comment: I have a similar project and it runs smoothly. Share with us also the countries.xsd and also what the problem is? It does not run? Your configuration seems correct to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar project and it works.

Try making your interface instead of

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://tsb.hcl.com/terp/ws/v2", name = "Terp-v2")
@XmlSeeAlso({com.hcl.psi.tsb.schema.common.ObjectFactory.class, com.hcl.psi.tsb.schema.offering.ObjectFactory.class, com.hcl.psi.kil.system.message.ObjectFactory.class, com.hcl.tsb.terp.ws.schema.ObjectFactory.class, com.hcl.psi.tsb.schema.task.ObjectFactory.class, com.hcl.psi.tsb.schema.servicecontract.ObjectFactory.class, com.hcl.psi.tsb.schema.project.ObjectFactory.class, com.hcl.tsb.tsb.ObjectFactory.class, com.hcl.psi.tsb.schema.customer.ObjectFactory.class})
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
public interface TerpV2 {

    @WebMethod(operationName = "GetServiceContracts")
    @WebResult(name = "GetServiceContractsResponseType", targetNamespace = "http://tsb.hcl.com/terp/ws/schema", partName = "payload")
    public com.hcl.tsb.terp.ws.schema.GetServiceContractsResponseType getServiceContracts(
        @WebParam(partName = "payload", name = "GetServiceContractsType", targetNamespace = "http://tsb.hcl.com/terp/ws/schema")
        com.hcl.tsb.terp.ws.schema.GetServiceContractsType payload
    ) throws TerpServiceFault;
```

like this

```
@Endpoint
public class TerpV2 {

    private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "Terp-v2";
    
 @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "GetServiceContractsType")   
 @ResponsePayload
public YourCustomResponseObject getServiceContracts(@RequestPayload GetServiceContractsType getServiceContractsType) {
    //this could be constructed in a service class
    YourCustomResponseObject response = new YourCustomResponseObject();
    
    return response;
}
```

Also in your configurations

```
wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("Terp-v2");
```

Also in your pom.xml configure the build like following

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <!-- Configuration excecutable=true i have added this to make the jar excecutable-->
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- Configuration classifier=exec i have added this to force maven create one Fat
                        excecutable jar but also another jar for the dependencies of the payload modules-->
                        <!--  <classifier>exec</classifier>-->
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>xjc</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xjc</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <sources>
                        <source>src/main/resources/countries.xsd</source>
                    </sources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

After you build your project it will compile your xsd and will produce in target some DTO classes. Those DTO classes you can copy then in your project and use them like actual DTOs. That's the easies way to convert your XSD to DTO to be used by spring boot.

To do this you must add the following dependency in your pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: what about xsd / Schema Location? Do i need to generate that and if i will not use that then?

Comment: you must put in resources your countries.xsd model. Share with me your model so I can see if everything seems good

Comment: Yes it appears .wsdl appears but i have 5 operations and in schema we can give one bean. I can see SchemaCollection class, appears it will be used for all 5 xsds?

Comment: Thanks. Yes i have done that. But xsd required seperately too? if we already have classes in project?

Comment: I am not sure to answer this. Try if it works without it and if not follow the proccedure that I have described above. That proccedure have at least worked for me

Comment: Hi both - I'm trying something similar, except I need to set the `@SOAPBinding` type to RPC - I can't figure out where in the Spring Boot annotations or which config class / bean I would set that on... any suggestions?